# ¿Se puede crear una variable en CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Quisiera crear una variable en CSS, para el color por ejemplo; donde al cambiar esa variable, se cambie el color de todos los elementos en los que use dicha variable

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]  . Esta no es la manera correcta de preguntar . Lectura obligatoria [ask].  por otra parte  tu pregunta se puede resolver buscado en Google unos minutos. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Si se puede, puedes agregarla en una clase .root, para crear la variable usas

```
--mi-color : #0000;
```

y para usarla usas

```
color : var( --mi-color ) .
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

(tendrías que poner este código en tu fichero css)

```
:root {
    --fuente-principal:  'Lato', sans-serif; 
    --primario: #da595e;
    --obscuro: #484848;
    --claro: #ffffff;
}
```

pongamos que quisieses cambiar el color de un background en ese mismo fichero por el color primario que hemos declarado, en ese caso agregaríamos la variable a el background de la siguiente manera

```
background-color: var(--primario);
```